# Clustering using categorical and continuous data together

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am trying to create a unsupervised model with categorical and continuous data together. I think I have worked it out, but is this the correct way to do this?

## Load Libraries

```
library(tidyr)
library(dummies)
library(fastDummies)
library(cluster)
library(dplyr)
```

## create sample data set

```
set.seed(3)
sampleData <- data.frame(id = 1:50, 
                     gender = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 10, replace = 
 TRUE),
                     age_bracket = sample(c("0-10", "11-30","31-60",">60"), 
 10, replace = TRUE),
                     income = rnorm(10, 40, 10),
                     volume = rnorm(50, 40, 100))
```

## Create sparse matrix and scale

```
sd1 <- sampleData  %>%
  dummy_cols(select_columns = c("gender","age_bracket"))%>%
  mutate(id = factor(id))%>%
  select(-c(gender,age_bracket))%>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, scale)

glimpse(sd1)
```

## Generate a k-means model using the pam() function with a k = 3

```
sd2 <- pam(sd1, k =3)
```

## Extract the vector of cluster assignments from the model

```
sd3 <- sd2$cluster
```

## Build the segment_customers dataframe

```
sd4 <- mutate(sd1, cluster = sd3)
```

## Calculate the size of each cluster

```
count(sd4, cluster)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dummy coding of variables is fairly standard, but I am not a fan of it. In many cases this IMHO causes large bias, and hinders interpretability.

In your case, you may additionally be applying standardization to them, which makes variable bias even worse.

Your text claims to use k-means, but uses PAM. These are not the same. PAM is IMHO a better choice here, because of interpretability, and the ability to use other metrics such as Manhattan. The resulting cluster "centers" are data points, not means.

I recommend going down to the mathematical level. PAM tries to minimize the sum of distances to the centers. Now put in the distance you use, e.g., Manhattan. Now substitute the standardization and dummy encoding in there, and you get the actual problem your approach tries to solve. Now have a critical look at this (probably quite large) term: is that helpful for your problem, or are you optimizing the wrong function?